# Is Research Right for me?

Tags: career-path, engineering, early-career

I am going to start college in a while and one of the programs I've applied for is a Bachelors in Technology followed by Masters in Science Program which is a consolidated program here and can be done in 5 years minimum and according to the statistics around 88% of the students manage to complete it in that time.

However I've always had Money as a major motivator over fame in the research field. I'd very well prefer having a Job at some Multi-National Company which is highly paying over being stuck with a PhD program afterwards. However with all of that said the program has a very high placement rate here with a Median salary comparable to other top non research courses.

I've applied for this course due to my childhood dream of finding something new or making a breakthrough but in Hindsight i don't feel I am well suited for research as I have never been able to stick to solving a problem for a while like I've read all these books and interviews by Top researchers who said they stuck with the problem for weeks and months and had this obsession since their childhood days but when I'm in a similar situation like when solving some questions and practicing my first instict after like some odd minutes of no progress is to look at the solution see how did they do it and then try doing it myself. I feel this will not be a good habit for research based studies.

I forgot to mention that the course is Computer Science based and the Masters programs offered are in Computational Natural Sciences, Computer Science and Engineering and Electronics and Communication Engineering.

I would like suggestions from people who've gone down similar paths or been at similar junctions of life.

Comment: You said you aren’t interested in being in a PhD program, a PhD program is all about research, if you don’t want to be in a PhD, then you don’t want to be in research.

Comment: A PhD Program is all about research I agree but it's the time that it takes which bothers me. I don't want to give up a significant proportion of my early years for that. I might pursue a part-time PhD later in my career but I do want to try out atleast some form of research that's why I went with the MS. Who knows maybe I'll then realize I am not as bad at research as I thought i would be and go ahead, besides the question right now is not about a PhD. People don't choose PhD for a variety of reasons other than not wanting to be in research @GrayLiterature

Comment: Research is a really bad way to get either money or fame.

Comment: It's not true that researchers are "obsessed," but being successful does take a lot longer than months.  Working on projects for a long time is something you can learn.

Comment: Can people develop the skills such as patience needed to be a good researcher? I've read interviews of many top researchers who made breakthroughs and a common trend was being different and striving in problems since there early childhood. I don't really want to go into research if i know i won't make it big if that's the case I'd rather go into the corporate world where money is there because eitherways I won't be getting any fame easily anywhere. @AnonymousPhysicist

Comment: @DinoManPhyLab You should not go into a research career because you want to "make it big". You should go into research because you want to make new discoveries and advance the field. However, get some experience of research during your degree and then reassess how you feel.

Comment: Yeah i guess that's the best way thanks for the suggestions :) @astronat

Comment: Can someone tell me the reason for all these downvotes?

Comment: Most likely downvoted because nobody can tell you what is and is not right for you.

Comment: The downvotes are because the question breaks the rules.  Those interviews you read are nonsense.  Some academics have worked since they are children, but that is not why they are successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give a number of reasons why you don't want a PhD and one reason why you might want it: A chance of a higher income after graduation. Is there anything else? If not, I would rather look for other ways to earn more money. A PhD is not the sure-fire way to make money. And lacking intrinsic motivation, you will most likely struggle more than others, have a higher chance of dropping out than others, and perhaps need more time to graduate.

That said, your PhD program is starting only in a few years. Preferences and motivations change and that change is hard to predict. Why not enroll in a research-based course in your undergrad studies, and take stock after the BA to reflect back on what you enjoyed about it and what you struggled with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although I didn't mention starting a PhD program in a few years anywhere did I get the wrong meaning from the last paragraph?

Comment: Yes, looks like it. Similar reasoning applies to going from BA to MA, though.

Comment: Oh got it still thanks for giving a concise answer

Comment: I do not agree.  Planning ahead is a very good idea.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist what's your suggestion? Drop the BA right away, or go for the BA but decide already now not to pursue a subsequent MA?

Comment: I am not making a suggestion, other than do not wait to form a plan.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist sure, but adjust your plan as you discover whether you enjoy research for its own sake..

Comment: A PhD is practically the complete opposite of a sure-fire way to make money.